# Unable to open SQL CE 4 databases in VS 2010 SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

According to "The Gu", in VS 2010 SP1 (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/01/11/vs-2010-sp1-and-sql-ce.aspx) I should be able to open SQL CE 4 databases.

However, when I try to do this I get the following error:

> "The data provider required to connect
>   to the local data file could not be
>   found. The file be added to the
>   project by the typed DataSet
>   associated with the file will not be
>   generated"

followed by the error:

```
"The operation could not be completed"
```

Note that this is for an ASP.NET MVC Project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some limitations in the SQL Compact 4 provider tooling, described here (under Scenarios not enabled by SQL Server Compact 4.0) - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2011/01/12/microsoft-sql-server-compact-4-0-is-available-for-download.aspx
In addition to the service pack, you must install the SQL Server Compact 4 tools on top - http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/12/visual-studio-tools-for-sql-server.html

Comment: this relates to Windows projects (I've updated my question to that effect). I'm effectively doing exactly what Scott does in his article (in asp.net MVC).

Answer (score 0):

My "solution" was just to open the database in web matrix to alter the schema.

Perhaps this was just an issue with the beta of VS 2010 SP1.

Comment: In addition to the service pack, you must install the SQL Server Compact 4 tools on top - http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/12/visual-studio-tools-for-sql-server.html

Comment: Thanks - please can you update your original answer with this point. I've marked it as the answer in advance.